# Bindable command in NET Maui for custom control is always null?

Tags: mvvm, binding, command, custom-controls, maui

I'm trying to implement a bindable command in a custom control based on Maps in order to provide action to clicking a pin in the maps control, but the OnSelectedPin command in the CustomMap is always null? I'm using MVVM and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

CustomMap.cs

```cs
public partial class CustomMap : Map
{
    ...

    public static readonly BindableProperty OnSelectedPinProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(OnSelectedPin),
            typeof(RelayCommand),
            typeof(CustomMap));

    public RelayCommand OnSelectedPin
    {
        get { return (RelayCommand)GetValue(OnSelectedPinProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OnSelectedPinProperty, value); }
    }

    ...

    private void Pin_Clicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method gets called when a pin in the map is clicked, 
        // but OnSelectedPin is always null

        if (OnSelectedPin?.CanExecute(null) ?? false)   //<-- HERE'S THE ISSUE
        {
            OnSelectedPin.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

MyPage.xaml

```
... 

<!-- Map -->
<controls:CustomMap
    Grid.Row="1"
    IsShowingUser="True"
    MapType="{Binding MapType}"
    CenterRegion="{Binding CurrentLocation}"
    OnSelectedPin="{Binding OnSelectedPinCommand}"/>

...
```

MyPage.cs

```cs
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage(MyPageViewModel ViewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MyPageViewModel.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
...

public partial class MyPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...

    [RelayCommand]
    public void OnSelectedPin()
    {
        var ii = 1;  // Just for debugging purposes
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of MVVM do you use?

Comment: The [Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm) is deprecated. You should use [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) as an alternative solution.

Comment: I've refactored the code to use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm and RelayCommands instead of ICommand but still the same issue.

Comment: I always call `InitializeComponent();` BEFORE `BindingContext = ...;`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> The name of the generated command will be created based on the method name. The generator will use the method name and append "Command" at the end, and it will strip the "On" prefix, if present. Additionally, for asynchronous methods, the "Async" suffix is also stripped before "Command" is appeneded.

So if you use "OnSelectedPin" as RelayCommand name, the generator will remove the prefix "On".

Then you use `OnSelectedPin="{Binding OnSelectedPinCommand}"`, will not find the RelayCommand.

So change the name, don't use a "On" prefix.

Hope it works.